# Computer only supports up to 32gb ram even though my cpu goes to 64

Tags: memory, cpu

My motherboard is 2 dimm. My cpu is intel i7 8770, which I checked supports up to 64 gb of ram. However, microcenter's website states my computer supports only up to 32gb. Why can't I have two 32gb ram sticks and goes up to 64? Can some components not handle 32gb ram sticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My CPU is Intel i7 8770, which I checked supports up to 64 GB of ram.

The Intel i7 8770 supports up to a maximum of 128 GB.  This means that it can support 32 GB modules.  Most 370 motherboards are only dual channel, which means there is only a single 128 GB configuration that is supported.  If that configuration is not supported by the motherboard, it means 32 GB DDR4 modules are not supported, which likely means only 16 GB modules are supported.  **The good news is that 32 GB modules are currently extremely rare.**

> However, the Micro Center's website states my computer supports only up to 32gb.

[Intel's specification page for your CPU confirms it supports up to a maximum of 128 GB.](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126686/intel-core-i7-8700-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html).  If the Micro Center website is indicating something different then the limitation is caused by your motherboard. **I am not aware of a single motherboard, that implements any of the 370 chipsets, that actually support 128 GB.**  It is worth pointing out, that I have seen several 390 motherboards that support 128 GB DDR4, which would support your processor.

> Why can't I have two 32gb ram sticks and goes up to 64?

Your system does not support it.  Your motherboard likely only has a single memory channel.  **This means you can only install 2 modules, the maximum size your motherboard supports, based on the description you provided the maximum size supported by your motherboard is 16 GB modules.**

> Can some components not handle 32gb ram sticks?

Most Intel motherboards do not support 32 GB DDR4 modules.  **DDR4 manufacturers have only recently started to produce 64 GB modules.**

Answer (score 2):

Your mainboard and your CPU each have their own capabilities. Your CPU will have one maximum, and your mainboard will have its own maximum supported RAM.

You are stuck with the lower of the two numbers on your system.

This is based on the design and components of your system. It's possible the CPU supports up to 4 16GB sticks, totalling 64GB, and since your mainboard only has 2 slots, you are stuck with the 32GB maximum.

Sometimes firmware updates can add support for previously unsupported amounts, but this is not super common.